# output the corresponding unique element

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, linq

i have a class

```
public class Error
{
    public string Message {get; set;}
    public string Recomendation {get; set;}
    public ErrorType errorType {get; set;}
}
```

Where ErrorType is enum which denotes a certain type of error

I receive a list of errors as input and want to receive the output as follows: print a Message for each element, and display a Recommendation only for the corresponding type of error like

input:

```
[err1, rec1, type1], 
[err2, rec1, type1], 
[err3, rec2, type2]
```

output:

```
err1
err2
rec1
err3
rec2
```

i think it can be implemented by by storing an intermediate variable while traversing the list, but I can't figure out what to do in edge cases or when the error type for all entities will be the same.
How can I implement this kind of logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using LINQ GroupBy which will allow you to group by error type or recommendation. Then you can iterate your groups and write out your error messages and recommendations:

```
// Assume variable "input" is an Enumerable of Error objects
var recommendations = input.GroupBy(err => err.Recomendation);
foreach (var errorTypeGroup in recommendations)
{
    foreach (var error in errorTypeGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(errorTypeGroup.Key); // Key will be the recommendation selected by the lambda
}
```